# Loading HTTP content within HTTPS with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, http, iframe, https

I have this code in a site over `HTTPS`, which works fine:

```
if(window.location.href == 'https:// example . com/'){
    $('body').append('<iframe id="iframe" src="//URL.000webhost.com"></iframe>');
}
```

With `//URL . 000webhost . com` (free subdomain, `HTTP`) works fine, but I bought another hosting with domain (`HTTP`) to load in `iframe` and now with new URL 
(//NEW DOMAIN . net) I see this error :

> vendor.js:2 GET https:// NEW DOMAIN . net/ net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Why in the free hosting works fine, but in new one doesn't and is there way if I make some domain settings to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path in the iframe (https:// instead of just //)
because the // will default use http and not https